# Pandas row multi-index with multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame containing some recorded data over time from a source, `data`:

```
   t  min  max ... some_value
 0.0  0.0  0.0 ...        0.0
 5.0  0.0  2.4 ...        1.9
10.0  0.0  6.7 ...        4.6
 ...  ...  ... ...        ...
```

I also have a data frame containing information about the source, `source`:

```
type location some_info
   A      loc      info
```

I now want to add `source` to `data` in a way that easily lets me get all the data from the selected source as I have data of multiple sources as well as access information about the source corresponding to the current data.
My idea was to do this with a multi-index in a way that I have something like

```
                           data
                              t  min  max ... some_value
source
  type location some_info
     A      loc      info   0.0  0.0  0.0 ...        0.0
                            5.0  0.0  2.4 ...        1.9
                           10.0  0.0  6.7 ...        4.6
   ...      ...       ...   ...  ...  ... ...        ...
```

Can this be done with a simple concatenation? It feels like it will be trickier than that.

If possible, I want to be able to iterate over the sources in a data frame containing data from multiple sources kind of like the following:

```py
for source in full_frame.index:
    source_data = full_frame[source,:]
    do_something(source_data)
```

If this approach seems unnecessarily complicated, please let me know.

EDIT: Updated the look of the wanted result

Comment: Without knowing a bit more about ```do_something(source_data)``` and assuming you have many locations, each with a ```data``` frame, it's probably easiest just to add a column to ```source``` dataframe that references [the name of] the corresponding ```data``` frame and get the data in two steps. I think the convenience of managing the data separately outweighs any benefit of making a single 'wide' dataframe in this case.

Comment: So you mean add a column to `source` like `source['ref']=data`?

Comment: No, a reference to ```data```. Maybe a string name that uniquely identifies each ```data``` dataframe. As I said, I don't know your use case, but the alternative is multi-value columns [a list in each cell] for the ```data``` columns, which may or may not be easier to manage.

Comment: I mainly want to analyze the data from different sources and plot the data. I could just use multiple data frames and always pass the name of the label to my `do_something()` which plots the data.

Comment: That sounds easiest :)

Comment: Having the source data in the data frame would have allowed me to filter different source parameters more easily though

Comment: you can still do that, unless you are looking for particular data values in the timeseries [I assume] in your ```data``` columns, but even then, the pandas expression is a bit more fiddly. If you are likely to want to do the analysis on these data frequently, then, ok, worth the investment in coding in a single dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
result = pd.concat([source, data], axis=1, join='outer', keys=['source', 'data'])
```

The concatenation takes place "by index" in both DataFrames.

I added *join='outer'* for proper behaviour if one DataFrame has a row
for some index value, but the second DataFrame doesn't.

Comment: I don't see a difference between having `join='outer'` versus not having it. Also, this results in the `result` frame having the data from `source` in the first row and `NaN` in the following rows. This is the same result as `result = pd.concat(dict(source=source, data=data), axis=1)`

Comment: Actually, yes. The default value for *join* is just *outer*.